# Created .db file using SQL Anywhere - now query it using RazorSQL

Tags: sql, database, sqlanywhere, razorsql

I created a .db file using Sybase SQL Anywhere, with loads of tables and information in it. Now, I dont have access to this Software anymore. So I got RazorSQL, which states on its homepage it can query SQL Anywhere. But how can I connect to my .db file using RazorSQL? Because I only found that it can connect to online databases.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like RazorSQL is an application that can connect to various types of databases. You still need a SQL Anywhere server running so that RazorSQL has something to connect to. If you can't run a SQL Anywhere server, you're out of luck.